# Shader - Camera Space top Vector

Tags: opengl, directx, glsl, shader, hlsl

I am not focused on a particular shader language. But I am trying to find a way to have a vector always coming from the top of my view.
Here are some screenshots to illustrate what I need.

**Edit:** I would like to obtain a mask. Here is a sample code for masking only bottom faces.

```
float mask = 1 - saturate(dot(float3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0), -worldNormal));
```

But the `float3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)` is not in the camera space and I would like to have it like the screenshots above.
It's maybe a matrix trick.

[image: reference1]
[image: reference2]
[image: reference3]

Comment: The camera's up-vector is the second row (or column, depending on your API) of the view matrix. If you don't have a pure view matrix, you can pass the vector as a shader variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot @NicoSchertler it's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to **[Nico Schertler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1210053/nico-schertler)**. The simplest way to have the camera's up-vector is to capture the second row of the view matrix.

[image: view matrix]

Here is an interesting article about it : [Understanding the View Matrix](http://3dgep.com/?p=1700)